# how to show quick type keyboard over the actual keyboard in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard

[image: how can I show spell checker(quick type view) over the actual keyboard]

Please check attached screenshot.
I need to show spell checker view[see the read highlighted rectangle] over the actually keyboard.

here,my Autocorrection of textfield is off.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This lib  may helps you。 [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager)